# Mailing list service with integrated image gallery

Tags: images, saas, mailing-list

I'm trying to find a solution to replace Yahoo groups for my paragliding club and I would like to hear your suggestion for service or software. We would like to move away from yahoo because of the many issue with this service: bugs and the UI, slow, lost messages, users needs to log on to view the galleries and attachments, etc.

The features we need are:

- A closed mailing list reserved to registered email senders and manageable by more than one person.
- Images posted to the list are stored on a web-based gallery and publicly available.

Additional feature that would be useful:

- Images are stripped from messages sent to the list and replaced with links.
- French version available (at least for the part the users will face. It's fine if I have to perform the translation myself)

Ideally, I'd love a free SaaS that does the above but if the service isn't free, I can work with it as well (although I'd have to go though the committee to agree).
If it's not possible to use a service, then I have access to VMs (Windows and Linux) that can be used to host applications (although, to be honest, I'd like to avoid that if possible for maintenance reasons).

Someone already suggested we use a Facebook group but several members (me included) would like to stay as far away from this service as humanly possible in this day and age.
I have also checked groups.io which is kinda OK except that there is, apparently, no way to make the image gallery public.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*TeamSnap*](https://www.teamsnap.com/) for this.

It is a service designed for clubs and similar, providing them with a web presence.

You can define access levels, create mailing lists, handle photographs.

It seems to suit all your requirements.

There are free and paid levels, dependent of course upon features and level of usage.

Comment: Thanks. I can't really figure out if it really fits our needs: it seems like a web-based tool, not a mail-based on. Have I missed something ?